# Can I set a WMP playlist with a string (path) array?

Tags: c#, winforms, wmp

Is there a way to created a WMP playlist using only the path names in C#?

I'm using Winforms, and have imported the WMPLib tool. I've already wrote code to extract all playable formats from the given directory and child-directories, but now I want to created a shuffled playlist using those string paths.

If this isn't possible, I think I'll use an autoplay feature using the saved list URLs, but it isn't as clean as creating a playlist.

Comment: create a wmp playlist by hand and look inside it. you will see how easy it is made. you can  then just recreate it with the paths. the header and footer will be the same, if i remember correctly.

Comment: Your goal is not clear.  Do you want to create a playlist for use by the `AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer` within your application (easy enough to do)? Or do you want to create a WMP playlist file (`somefile.wpl`) on disk?